# Dynamic Form validation (not just the fields)

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, dynamic, jquery-validate

I'm trying to figure out how to do dynamic form validation with jquery, and jquery's validation plugin.  I'm fairly new to jquery, and JS in general.

I've figured out how to get the validation to occur when I click submit (using the submitHandler).  However I need to POST via ajax, not the native way.  So I need to preventDefault, and I don't seem to be able to.  The native way to me is when you click submit, the action occurs.  I don't want the action to occur as I'm attempting to do it via $.ajax({...});.

If I put the validation in the $('#form').live('click', function(e) {...}), I can now post via ajax, however validation doesn't occur.  I've got everything inside the $(document).ready(function() {...};.

How can I get a dynamic form validated inside the live('click') method?  I've tried to call validate() when I add the form.  I add an entire form via a click on an object, and append to a child object.

Either way (in the submitHandler, or by using live('click')) is fine by me, but I can't seem to figure out either way.

Hopefully that's enough information, but if not I'll be happy to provide more. A small snippet of the submitHandler below.

```
   $("#form-" + $(this).attr('id')).validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       this.preventDefault();
       // My ajax function below (submitForm);
       submitForm(this);
       alert('wee');
     }
```

Comment: OK, so I fixed this.  I was using the wrong bloody object...

`code submitForm(this)` should have been:
`code submitForm(form);`
AFTER I altered the validate line, and added an additional line before the validate line:
`code
var form = "#form-" + $(this).attr('id');
$(form).validate({
`
my final version is:
`code
      var form = "#form-" + $(this).attr('id');
      $(form).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) { //Only runs when valid
          submitForm(form);
        }
      });
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at [jQuery (ajax) form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form)?

Comment: I think your solution worked the best.  Thanks, I modified it a bit, and showed how I acheived what I needed to as a comment to my question.

Thanks.

Comment: No problem, it's nice to help out.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the submitHandler correctly. Try this:

```
 $("#myform").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
      }
 });
```

And then override the submit function for the form:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    //do something with the AJAX response
  });

  return false;
});
```

The return false; at the end will prevent the default form submission.

Comment: The problem you have here is that you're not reading my problem (I think).  I don't know the form's name until I load it via ajax, so while this would work great with a static form, I am not using static forms.

I've tried to build the $(..).submit({}); every time I add a row, but that's not working right.

`code
      var form = "#form-" + $(this).attr('id');
      $(form).submit(function() {
        submitForm(form);
      }).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          form.submit();
        }
`